# Browse associative array as circular list

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to browse an associative array like a circular list.
First the associative array is defined like this :

```
array = {item1:array(...), item2:array(...), ...}
```

When at the first element I browse the array of this element, once arrive at the last element of this array it should passe to the second element and brows it's array, and the same for the last one who must return to the first element.

so I initialize my array as follows:

```
// Build the associative array

Prot.prototype.additem = function(itemName, itemArray)
{
    this.array[itemName] = itemArray; // itemArray is an array
}

// Init the currentItem of the associative array to browse (We don't necessarily start at the first)

Prot.prototype.init = function(itemName)
{
    this.currentItem = this.array[itemName];
    this.currentItemArray = 0; 

}


Prot.prototype.next = function()
{   
    // here I browse the first array of the first key of my associative array
    var index = this.currentItem.indexOf(this.currentItemArray);
    index = index +1;
    this.currentItemArray = this.currentItem[index];
    if (index == (this.currentItemArray.length - 1)) 
    {   
        // when arrives at the last element of the array of the first key I should pass to the second
        return false;
    } 
    else {
        return true;        
    }

}

// I add a set interval at the end so no need for a loop
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your variable says "array" but it points to an object. JS has objects with key-value pairs and `Map`s, not associative arrays. Please show valid syntax and semantics, otherwise it's pretty unclear what you need. Thanks.

Comment: "associative arrays" are called objects in JavaScript and are not handled like arrays.

Comment: Typo: `itmeName` should be `itemName`

Comment: Object properties aren't ordered in JS (ES6 says that non-numeric properties remember the order that they were added, but it's tricky to use this with random properties). If you want something that preserves order, use an array.

Comment: please add some data and the wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an associative array in JavaScript, but you can use an object instead. A very simple implementation of defining an object and referencing its properties in a circular way would be the following:

```js
// define the object with 6 properties and assiociated values:
var obj={a:123, b:456, c:789, d:666, e:777, f:888};

function getcirc(obj){
  // use a "static variable" inside the function:
  if(typeof getcirc.i=="undefined") getcirc.i=0;
  var keys=Object.keys(obj), k=keys[getcirc.i++%keys.length];
  console.log(k,obj[k]);
}

// call the function repeatedly ...
for (var n=0;n<20;n++) getcirc(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an array to know what is the "next" item array. So I would suggest storing the desired order in another array, having just those names.

Here is a possible implementation:

```js
class Prot {
    constructor() {
        this.itemNames = [];
        this.arrays = {};
        this.hasData = false;
        this.currentIndex = 0; 
    }
    additem(itemName, itemArray) {
        if (itemName in this.arrays) throw "duplicate entry";
        this.arrays[itemName] = { data: itemArray, index: this.itemNames.length };
        this.itemNames.push(itemName); // keep the order
        if (itemArray.length) this.hasData = true;
    }
    init(itemName) {
        this.currentItem = this.arrays[itemName];
        this.currentIndex = 0; 
    }
    next() {
        if (!this.hasData) return;
        if (!this.currentItem) this.currentItem = this.arrays[this.itemNames[0]];
        var data = this.currentItem.data[this.currentIndex++];
        while (this.currentIndex >= this.currentItem.data.length) {
            this.currentItem = this.arrays[this.itemNames[(this.currentItem.index+1) % this.itemNames.length]];
            this.currentIndex = 0;
        } 
        return data;
    }
}

// demo
let obj = new Prot;
// add the arrays:
obj.additem("a", [1, 2, 3]);
obj.additem("b", [4, 5]);
obj.additem("c", [6, 7, 8, 9]);
obj.additem("d", [0]);
// Start at "b":
obj.init("b");

// iterate from there...
for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    console.log(obj.next());
}
```